# Behavior of a complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

The question is as follows:

> Investigate the behavior of $\sum\frac1{1+z^n}$ for complex values of $z$.

I started by rewriting $z$ as $z = a + bi$ for some $a,b\in\Bbb R$ but I'm not sure where to go from here as I'm not incredibly familiar with operations on complex numbers. Any help is very appreciated!

edit: thanks for rewriting this to make it look better, I wasn't sure how to do it!

Comment: How would you solve it if z were real?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas with very basic complex weaponry:

We can write $\;z=re^{it}\;,\;\;r=|z|\;,\;\;t=\arg z\implies z^n=r^ne^{nit}\;$ , and thus

$$|1+z^n|=|1+r^ne^{nit}|=|(1+r^n\cos nt)+ir^n\sin nt|=$$

$$=\sqrt{1+2r^n\cos nt+r^{2n}}\ge r^{n/2}\sqrt{r^n+2\cos nt}$$

Observe that for $\;r>1\;$ the expression within the square roots is almost always non-negative and, in fact, almost always greater than $\;1\;$ , so

$$\frac1{|1+z^n|}\le\left(\frac1{\sqrt{|z|}}\right)^n$$

and the series of the rightmost expression is a geometric one with positive ratio  less than one.

Comment: Hmm....I think I see what you're saying a bit. The only issue is that I'm currently in an Analysis I class, and the only complex information we've been given is that a complex z can be written as z = a + bi for a, b real. Thus, while I'm sure what you're saying here is completely correct, I think it might be a little too apparent to my professor that this work isn't my own.

Comment: @mizichael I never intended to give you something to produce to your instructor as if it were your own work, but something to work with *in your own personal way*. Perhaps there's some other, more basic way.

Comment: sorry - I didn't mean to imply I was just going to plagiarize your work. I just meant your explanation is a bit foreign to me. I'm not trying to get someone to give me the answer, I'm just trying to figure out where to begin a proof.

Comment: I very much appreciate your help, though!